# Tense usage in relation to date of birth of deceased individuals

Tags: tenses

Let's say Bob passed away. Would we say, "Bob's birthdate was xxx" or "Bob's birthdate is xxx"? Birthdates don't change, which makes me inclined to use 'is', but sounds a little weird if the person is deceased.

Comment: related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22249/is-it-correct-to-use-the-word-birthday-for-the-deceased-or-is-there-a-better

Comment: There is no longer a "Bob" to *have* a birthday. Bob doesn't exist. If you were talking about a shirt you found, you would not say "That's Bob's shirt!", you'd say "That *was* Bob's shirt". Bob is no more, and neither is his birthday.  RIP, Bob.

Comment: @dan bron Are you sure you're not confusing with birthday ? Bob birthday was xxx . he doesn't have a birthday anymore (i.e birthday is a day where his birth is celebrated,) but Bob birth date  is xxx (the date of birth does not change). Otherwise said one may  have up to 121 birthDAYS through one's life but only one birthDATE.

Comment: @P.Obertelli - Bob's date of birth was xxx. He was born on that date. I'm not a lawyer and can't speak to his property, but in common usage, *was* is correct.

Comment: Interesting, I'm curious to see some answer with reference. People probably make the same confusion as you, after all, you answered  about birthDAY even though the question was BirthDATE.  I tried ngram & google book for birthdate is /was I could not find a definite answer about usage.

Comment: Here is an example from this March ... http://thechive.com/2016/03/14/today-is-albert-einsteins-birthday-he-would-have-wanted-you-to-learn-something-20-photos/ "Today is Einstein's Birthday"

Comment: @PhilSweet — Good point. Have submitted suggested modification.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm referring to the use of birthDATE.

Answer (score 2):

Bob's date of death *is* xxx.

The late Bob's date of birth (DOB) or birth date  *is* / *was* xxx.

It just depends on what spin you want to put on it. If you are talking regarding the factual DOB for this guy, feel free to use *is*, as it still *is* his DOB.

If you are talking more about *Bob*, or want to recognize that the guy has passed away, feel free to use *was*.

I would probably use *was* in most cases because the person whose DOB we are talking about has [gone west](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334078/origin-of-the-phrase-go-west-to-die).